# INSERT INTO syntax error but normally should work

Tags: php, mysql

I'm repeatedly getting a syntax error when inserting in to mysql, normally this works fine but I can't seem to get it to work. I can echo out the variables no problem but for some reason I can't insert them.

variables (the session vars are brought over from another page)

```
session_start();
$name=$_SESSION['bName'];
$email=$_SESSION['email'];
$ship_address = $_SESSION['sAddress'];
$voucher=$_SESSION['voucher'];
$sku=$_SESSION['sku'];
$credit_card=$_POST['credit_card'];
$security_code=$_POST['security_code'];
$payment_type=$_POST['payment_type'];
$cc_number=substr($credit_card, 0, 4) . str_repeat('x', (strlen($credit_card) - 4)) . substr($credit_card, -4, 4);
$phone=$_SESSION['billPhone'];
$status="Redeemed";
$date = date('Y/m/d');
$tracking ="";
```

insert query

```
//Insert Queries
$sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO `customers`(`name`, `email`, `address`, `phone`, `sku`, `creditcard`, `securitycode`, `paymenttype`, `voucher`, `purchase_id`, `tracking`, `status`, `date_recieved`) 

VALUES( $name, $email, $ship_address, $phone, $sku, $credit_card, $security_code, $payment_type, $voucher, $purchase_id, $tracking, $status, $date)";
    mysql_query($sqlInsert) or die ('Error Inserting into database' . mysql_error());
```

I've also tried

```
VALUES( '$name', '$email', '$ship_address', '$phone', '$sku', '$credit_card', '$security_code', '$payment_type', '$voucher', '$purchase_id', '$tracking', '$status', '$date')
```

but it doesn't work. The error I get is

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'lastname, fahad@semail.com, 22 toronto ont l6a0l4, 416-123-4567, 1001234, 1234567' at line 1
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Do `echo $sqlInsert` and post the output. You have to put string values into quotes, the latter method should work **but** you have to escape & sanitize the values!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all string values must be quoted.

`VALUES("'.$name.'", "'.$email.'"` ...

Comment: Thanks, that worked just fine! '".$name."' instead of "'.$name.'" in case anyone else has the same problem. Strange though I dont usually have to do that. just using '$name' usually works just fine. Oh well thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this, so the fields are delimited:

```
VALUES( '$name', '$email', ...
```

check your error message to see what kind of garbage you are currently generating.

Answer (score 1):

You could use PDO to [create prepared statements](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) instead. Then you won't have to worry about escaping your values like drdwilcox's example 'Jerry''s'. It also helps as a counter measure against SQL Injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

I would almost guarantee that you have a single-quote in your name field. If you want to place a single quote into a string field in SQL, you must double it: 'Jerry''s'

And you need the `'$name'` version.